# deserialize gson object using GSONConverter

Tags: json, gson

I need to deserialize a gson response 
Here is the format.
{"lastid":"5", "testimonials":["a","b","c"]}

Pls suggest for DTO's and conversion.

```
public class TestimonialsOutputDTO implements Serializable {
public String lastid;
public List<TestimonialsDTO> testimonials;

public String getLastid() {
    return lastid;
}

public void setLastid(String lastid) {
    this.lastid = lastid;
}

public List<TestimonialsDTO> getTestimonials() {
    return testimonials;
}

public void setTestimonials(List<TestimonialsDTO> testimonials) {
    this.testimonials = testimonials;
}

}
```

and

```
public class TestimonialsDTO
{
public String testimonials;

public String getTestimonials() {
    return testimonials;
}

public void setTestimonials(String testimonials) {
    this.testimonials = testimonials;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can parse `"testimonials":["a","b","c"]` in Java List directly instead of creating your own custom pojo.

Here your model class.

```
public class TestimonialsOutputDTO {

    public String lastid;
    public List<String> testimonials;

// getter/setter
// toString()

}
```